# Trouble in query from ms access to vb.net

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access

have a problem at what im doing right now in VB.net. I have a query in MS access and i want to run it in VB.net. my query run in MS ACCESS but when i try to run it in VB it doesn't show results. I've noticed that when I change the numbers on on the IIF statements true and false part to lower number it shows results. here is my code sir/mam.

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Public Class Form1
Dim connect As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    connect = New OleDb.OleDbConnection
    connect.ConnectionString = "Provider = microsoft.jet.oledb.4.0; data source = E:\Fb1.mdb"
    If Not connect.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
        connect.Open()
    End If

    Dim strSQL As String

    strSQL = "Select * FROM f_7_fSpecies_new WHERE f7Species Like '*iger';"
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    ds.Tables.Add(dt)
    Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter

    da = New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT f7SynonymId, f7Species, Left(f7Species, Len(f7Species)), Right(f7Species, 1), Left(f7Species, Len(f7Species)-IIF(Right(f7Species, 1) In ('a','r'),2,3)) As f7Species_Root " & _
                             "FROM f_7_fSpecies_new " & _
                            "WHERE f_7_fSpecies_new.f7Species Like '*iger'; ", connect)

    da.Fill(dt)
    DataGridView1.DataSource = dt.DefaultView
    Me.DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
    connect.Close()
End Sub

End Class
```

The criteria also didn't show result.